# SharePoint custom edit form button javascript onclick set fields value

Tags: javascript, custom-form

I'm fairly new to developing and I have a custom form that I made using SharePoint designer 2010 - I need to start my workflow on the click of the button, but I'm not using a site based workflow, so my code for the start button doesn't work. My alternative is to have onclick set fields value (I have a hidden text field called start workflow) to yes.

For now this is what I have

```
<input name="StartWorkflow" type="button" value="Start Workflow" onclick=””/>
```

This is what I've found - but I don't believe its correct to go in my onclick event.

I’m finding information relative to things outside of SharePoint so it’s confusing to put two and two together – I did find this information

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function updateListItem() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(3);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My Updated Title');

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Also does anyone know how to create a onclick= redirect to.."www..etc"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID of the list item from the query string which you can pass in your code.

You can then pass your hidden field in set_item. Though just modifying any field will cause the workflow to run if you've set the workflow to run on modification.

Also, a simple `window.location` can help you redirect to another Url.